# Value in component logs in console but won't show in template - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

All,

I have a simple yet unsolved scenario that I haven't been able to figure out for a while. I have been using Angular for about the last 3 years and have solved a lot of different problems. This one seems super simple yet I cannot figure it out. It's one of those problems that really makes you question your understanding of things.

Quite simply, I have a loader that is called in various parts of our application. the loader can get the progress of another process elsewhere by subscribing to a subject.asObservable() inside of a service like so.

```
constructor(
    public _dialog: DialogService,
    public ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private zone: NgZone,
  ) {

}
```

where another process (that we're trying to show the progress of) sends new progress values by

```
this.dialog.loadingBarCurrentIndex.next(currentIndex);
```

In our loader, we have the following inside of our constructor...

```
//given _loadingBarCurrentIndex$ is loadingBarCurrentIndex.asObservable()

this._dialog._loadingBarCurrentIndex$.pipe(
   takeUntil(this.destroyed) //I know I can use map here to tackle rounding the value, not my concern right now
).subscribe((res) => {
   if(this.ci !== Math.round(res)) { //this is here so I don't process 100s of values per second
      this.ci = Math.round(res); 
      console.log(this.ci);
    }
});
```

And in our template we have the following:

```
<ngb-progressbar type="success" id="transition-bar" value="{{ci}}"></ngb-progressbar>
<p style="color: white;">{{ci}}</p>
```

What I can't figure out is why would `this.ci` console log just fine, but not show up whatsoever in the loading bar or the paragraph element?

I have tried several different things to try and force `this.ci` to show up properly in the component. I've forced change detection each time the variable is updated, I've run the entire subscription inside of `this.zone.run(() => {HERE})` I've tried putting the subscription into different lifecycle hooks (assuming that the DOM wasn't rendering the loading bar properly, that I might've been trying to shove a value in there too soon), and I've put various parts of the subscription into a `setTimeout(() => {}, 200)` just to see if the DOM had a problem updating the value. Still no cigar.

Does anybody have any idea as to what is going on? Am I lacking some fundamental understanding somewhere? I have never had a problem getting a value to show up properly in any template before and this seems like it shouldn't be a problem either....

Update:

I have also tried just getting the observable itself in my component and then using the async pipe like so:

```
<p>{{_dialog._loadingBarCurrentIndex$ | async}}</p>
```

Still no luck...

This loading bar is inside of a Mat-Dialog. Does that matter here? I would think not if we are still able to get the progress values, but I'm not sure.

It's as though change detection just doesn't fire inside of this dialog...

Comment: And you are not getting a compile error? I got compile error when trying `value="{{ci}}"` needed to use `[value]="ci"`. ng-bootstrap v10 - angular v12.0.5

Comment: I've tried it that way as well... No errors on compilation in either scenario. We're on ng-bootstrap v7, angular 10 at the moment

Comment: Hmm. Best would be if you could reproduce this in a Stackblitz.

Comment: What is the value of this.ci? You could remove <ngb-progressbar> and use only <p> to find where the problem is.

Comment: ci is declared as a number equal to 0 in the component. It doesn't matter about removing the progress bar. the paragraph element fails to pick up the value as well